# How to use a inner join with 2 conditions in the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, inner-join

I'm trying to do an INNER JOIN of a few tables, but with certain condition:

I have the CONTACTS table:

```
code                contact_type                  name               email
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                       P                       AAAAAAAA            SSSS@DDD.COM
2                       P                        BBBBBBB             SDFSDF@DDD.COM
3                       P                         CCCCC              SDSDF@DD.COM
1                       C                        AAAABBB             DDDD@DDD.COM
2                       C                        BBBBCCC             DSDF@DD.COM
3                       C                        CCCCDDD             ASSAD@DD.COM
```

the PROVIDERS table:

```
code                               name
----------------------------------------------------
1                                  SIEMENS
2                                  FUJITSU
3                                  ASUS
```

and the CLIENTS table:

```
CODE                                     NAME
---------------------------------------------------------
1                                       SMITH
2                                       PETER
3                                       MICHAEL
```

I like to select all rows from the contacts, but when CONTACT_TYPE is `C` appears the correspondent `CLIENT.name` to this code, and when the CONTACT_TYPE is `P` appears the correspondent `PROVIDER.NAME`,

I try:

```
SELECT code,contact_type,con.name,con.EMAIL 
FROM contacts con 
  inner join CLIENTS cli 
    on cli.codcli=con.CODE 
   and con.CONTACT_TYPE='C'
  inner join provIDERS p 
     on con.CODE=p.codpro 
    and con.CONTACT_TYPE='P'
```

But doesn't work,

I also try:
[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb8ad/2)

and I want to see like this:

```
PROVIDER/CLIENT NAME            CONTACT_TYPE                      EMAIL
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SIEMENS                             P                          SSSS@DDD.COM
FUJITSU                             P                          SDFSDF@DDD.COM 
ASUS                                P                          SDSDF@DD.COM
SMITH                               C                          DDDD@DDD.COM
PETER                               C                          DSDF@DD.COM
MICHAEL                             C                          ASSAD@DD.COM
```

[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb8ad/2)

Comment: why dont you put con.CONTACT_TYPE='P'  and con.CONTACT_TYPE='C'  after where clause?

Comment: First of all check your data - The Clients table Code column values don't match with the Contacts table Code column values for the result set you want.

Comment: @OZY if i put after the where li you say dont obtain any rows, because no code is P and C

Comment: I edited to put the correct data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use this query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN CONTACT_TYPE = 'C' THEN
            (SELECT Name FROM CLIENTS c WHERE c.Code = co.Code)
        WHEN CONTACT_TYPE = 'P' THEN
            (SELECT Name FROM PROVIDERS p WHERE p.Code = co.Code)
    END AS [PROVIDER/CLIENT NAME],
    CONTACT_TYPE, EMAIL
FROM
    CONTACTS co;
```

[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb8ad/4)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do it with union:

```
SELECT  p.Name AS [Provider/Client Name] ,
        c.Contact_Type ,
        c.Email
FROM    contacts c
        INNER JOIN providers p
        ON c.code = p.code
WHERE  c.Contact_Type = 'P'
UNION
SELECT  cl.Name AS [Provider/Client Name] ,
        c.Contact_Type ,
        c.Email
FROM    contacts c
        INNER JOIN client cl
        ON  cl.code = p.code
WHERE   c.Contact_Type = 'C'
```

or by use case statement:

```sql
SELECT  CASE
        WHEN c.Contact_Type = 'P' THEN 
            (SELECT p.Name FROM providers p WHERE p.code = c.code)
        ELSE 
            (SELECT cl.Name FROM client cl WHERE cl.code = c.code) END
        AS [Provider/Client Name] ,
        c.Contact_Type ,
        c.Email
FROM    contacts c
```

Comment: I think using `UNION ALL` in this case can be better and faster ;).

Comment: You are right @ShA.T, in this case will no be duplicates, so union all is more faster

Answer (score 1):

Try using `left join`:

```
SELECT code, contact_type, con.name, con.EMAIL 
FROM contacts con left join
     CLIENTS cli
     on cli.codcli =c on.CODE and
        con.CONTACT_TYPE = 'C' left join
     providers p 
     on con.CODE = p.codpro and
        con.CONTACT_TYPE = 'P' ;
```

An `inner join` requires that each row match *both* tables at the same time.  That is clearly impossible, given the conditions.  So, use `left join`.

For your actual results:

```
SELECT coalesce(con.name, p.name) as name, cli.contact_type, cli.email 
FROM contacts con left join
     CLIENTS cli
     on cli.codcli = con.CODE and
        con.CONTACT_TYPE = 'C' left join
     providers p 
     on con.CODE = p.codpro and
        con.CONTACT_TYPE = 'P' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is something like this :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN C.ContactType = 'P' THEN P.Name,
        WHEN C.ContactType = 'C' THEN C.Name,
        ELSE 'Unknown' END AS ProviderClientName,
        C.ContactType,
        C.Name
FROM CONTACTS C WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN CLIENTS CL WITH(NOLOCK) ON C.Code = CL.Code
LEFT JOIN PROVIDERS P WITH(NOLOCK) ON C.Code = P.Code
```

But check your data, as joining between the Contacts and Clients tables from your example will not return matches.